# JavaScript checking vs Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next code in my react js application:

```
interface Input {
  name: string;
  type?: 'email' | 'text';
}

const Input = ({type}: Input) => {

return <input type={type}/>
}
```

The component can receive only type `email` and `text`. If the user will add as a prop `number` then the compiler will throw an error in compilation time. EX:

```
<Input type="number"/>
```

```
Type '"password"' is not assignable to type '"text" | "email".
```

, but in the same time we can anyway to type:

```
<Input type="number"/>
```

even with this error and to suppress the error.

**Question**: Should i restrict the `type` props only using typescript like in my case or should i use javascript to exclude the situation when the `type` will be `number`?

Comment: TypeScript does not enforce anything at runtime, only at transpile. If you want runtime prop checking, try the package [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types)

Comment: @casraf, if using typescript should i check again the type prop using javsscript or  typescript is enough?

Comment: Like I said, if you want to enforce types during runtime (i.e., when the JS actually runs on the browser), you can't use TypeScript alone as it doesn't add any JS code that checks the values, and you will have to do it inside the JS code, either manually or with the package I mentioned. If you only need to enforce them while writing code, i.e. before compilation happens, then TS is the only thing you need. TS = compilation only. JS = during runtime.

Comment: @casraf, ok, but according best practices, if i use Typescript, it is enough or should i exclude somehow the scenario when user will use something different than: `text` and `email `.?

Comment: If someone uses your package and doesn't use TypeScript, they will have no way of knowing what your properties expect, and it won't tell them anything for trying. If you intentionally want to limit the available options to the user consuming your package, you might want to add some runtime-checking logic to it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tradeoff of safety, speed, and your own development time. You'll need to decide this based on your use-case: it's a matter of judgment, not of universal best practice. Though runtime checks would make your code safer and more complete to test at runtime, it may not provide much value for a component for which you're the only user, and that you use a limited number of times.

I could see it going either way here; you'll need to decide based on your understanding of the benefits and costs.

Good times to add extra defensive checks even when TypeScript makes errors unlikely:

- in migrated codebases where there is a lot of usage of `any`, implicit or explicit
- in large codebases with external users or lots of internal users
- where stakes are high: the component is critical or a misuse would introduce subtle errors later
- in component initialization or cases that happen infrequently per application, where the overhead of an extra check is negligible
- for values that are frequently dynamic or user-supplied, like `value`
- where automated tests elsewhere are difficult, or unlikely to catch this

Conversely, runtime defensive checks may be overkill in these cases:

- where use of TypeScript is endemic: it's very unlikely someone would override a type check
- in small codebases where you might be the only one calling this
- in low-stakes environments, either because the behavior is obviously wrong or it has minimal consequences
- in tight inner loops or where runtime checking would be expensive performance-wise
- for values that are unlikely to be user-supplied, like `type`
- where other testing would likely catch this